# Is there a quick way to apply left and right margins to elements in the inside of a horizontal list but not to the outside?

Tags: html, css

If I have a list of elements like below, and I'm using flexbox to position them so that they're all horizontally aligned and taking up equal amounts of space. I want to apply a margin to the inner elements so that there is a slight gap between all of them.

However, I also don't want the margin to apply to the outer two elements, as this will cause misalignments since we're pushing the outer elements inwards by giving them a margin.

Essentially, I want the inner two elements to have a left and right margin, while the first element has a right margin and the last element has a left margin. That way all of the margins are equal, but there are no margins on the outside of the elements.

You can do it by applying individual styles on the specific cards, but I just wondered if there was a better way to do it than this.

```
<div class="service-card-container">
        <mat-card class="service-card" style="margin-right: 10px;">
            <p>Card</p>
        </mat-card>
        <mat-card class="service-card" style="margin-right: 10px;margin-left: 10px;">
            <p>Card</p>
        </mat-card>
        <mat-card class="service-card" style="margin-right: 10px;margin-left: 10px;">
            <p>Card</p>
        </mat-card>
        <mat-card class="service-card" style="margin-left: 10px;">
            <p>Card</p>
        </mat-card>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can offset the margins of the first and last elements with a negative margin of the same amount on the parent:

```css
.service-card-container {
  margin-left: -10px;
  margin-right: -10px;
}

.service-card {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

… OR, you can target the first and last elements and remove their left and right margins respectively.

```css
.service-card {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.service-card:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.service-card:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

Comment: I always forget those selectors exist, works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```css
.service-card {
margin-right: 20px;
}

.service-card:last-child {
margin-right: 0;
}
```

This way, you can style all the `mat-card` items with a right margin value of 20px. Then you can remove the right margin value from the last `mat-card` thereby making sure there is consistent margin between the items inside the container, yet ensuring there is no leaking margin on the last item.